# Performance issue on creating new topic

Tags: rocketmq

Currently, we have VM configured with 18GB ram, 8 core CPU.

We are running broker and nameserver both on the same machine.

As of now, we have around 3563 topics. So, name server and broker consuming 13 GB from 18GB.

I am facing latency issue on creating a new topic. (For new topic creating it taking around 13 to 15 seconds).

I am looking to create a topic in just fraction of the second.

Can I know a reason for this latency issue?

Quick note: We looking to create millions of topic in RocketMQ.
We also understand it needed sufficient ram/core to manages these.

Is RocketMQ quite enough to handle millions of topics...?

Comment: same issue here.In local system, topic is creating very fast.More than 4000 topics are there in my local system. But in VM, topic creation is taking to much time. sometimes 10/15 min.I have VM with 20GB ram , 8 core cpu.

Comment: What do you mean latency? Do you mean the topic stored in file? or the clients to discover this topic?

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem also. When I create a topic ,the command line timeout with 3000ms.The lower version has this problem.The reason I will explain below:

1.client send new topic config to each of broker, then wait for broker register all of topic configs to namesrv.

2.If you have a large number of topic, then the process will costs more than 3000ms and result in a timeout.

The higher version's process was changed!

1.client send new topic config to each of broker, then broker return success at once and register all of topic configs to namesrv async.

By the way, although timeout occurred but the topic create success you can verify it by use topicRoute command.If you want to reduce the latency on create topic, you will figure out a mechanism which need not register the whole topic configs to namesrv.